# Create redirect page with template tags included for single.php

Tags: php, http-redirect

I want to make each visited single page is first redirected to template.php page that has original targeted post permalink like **AdFly shorten url service**.

As for now it works using [PHP header() Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). But I couldn`t figure out how to get original source page permalink to be included in template.php

```
<?php
 header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
 header("Location: http://www.yournewwebsite.com/template.php");
?>
```

Comment: So for example, if I go to `http://google.com`, you want to redirect to `htttp://yourwebsite.com/template.php` then it redirects me to google?

Comment: @KayVan `blog.com/post_id=14` redirects to `blog.com/page.php` that has a link included to `blog.com/post_id=14`

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the link as a parameter in the location.

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://example.com/template.php?website=" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

And in your `template.php`, simply do `$_GET['website']` to retrieve the url passed in the param.